# how to make clippy fix pedantic errors

Tags: rust, rust-clippy

I can go

```
cargo clippy --fix
```

and it will fix default things

I can go

```
 cargo clippy -- -D clippy::pedantic
```

And it will complain about a lot more, but

```
cargo clippy --fix --allow-dirty  -- -D clippy::pedantic
```

does not fix things , and caps it off by saying

```
warning: `db65` (bin "db65") generated 415 warnings (run `cargo clippy --fix --bin "db65"` to apply 47 suggestions)
```

even though that suggested clippy command does nothing

Comment: What are there warnings? Are you sure that they're automatically fixable (this one - https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#/case_sensitive_file_extension_comparisons?groups=pedantic - for example, isn't)?

Comment: clippy says that some are fixable `run cargo clippy --fix --bin "db65" to apply 47 suggestions`

Comment: Please add a [mre] of a fixable, pedantic lint, that doesn't get fixed with `--fix`.